# Kivy Won't download with pip

Tags: python, module, kivy, python-module

I can't get Kivy to install with pip.
This is what I wrote in command prompt

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\Test>python -m pip install kivy[full]
Collecting kivy[full]
  Using cached Kivy-2.1.0.tar.gz (23.8 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [10 lines of output]
      Collecting setuptools
        Using cached setuptools-67.6.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
      Collecting wheel
        Using cached wheel-0.40.0-py3-none-any.whl (64 kB)
      Collecting cython!=0.27,!=0.27.2,<=0.29.28,>=0.24
        Using cached Cython-0.29.28-py2.py3-none-any.whl (983 kB)
      Collecting kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev~=0.3.3
        Using cached kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev-0.3.3-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (3.9 MB)
      ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement kivy_deps.sdl2_dev~=0.4.5 (from versions: 0.5.1, 0.6.0)
      ERROR: No matching distribution found for kivy_deps.sdl2_dev~=0.4.5
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I was expecting it to work and I've tried creating a virtual environment, but no it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

(I am not able to comment so I post is as answer, my apologies)

Did you try 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' before you tried to install kivy